# Change UEFI boot order from busybox

Tags: boot, uefi, boot-loader, busybox

After generate a new efi boot entry with efibootmgr:

```
# efibootmgr -c -g -L "Debian (EFI stub)" -l '\EFI\debian\vmlinuz' -u "root=UUID=955548bd-9c77-4893-8633-3a5e7966dfc9 ro quiet rootfstype=ext4 add_efi_memmap initrd=\\EFI\\debian\\initrd.img"
```

The system doesn't start, only fall into a BusyBox shell.

How is possible to change the boot order to the old entry? Something like

```
# efibootmgr -o 0004,0005,0000,0001,0002,0003
```

Comment: That's Debian fail, not UEFI fail. UEFI doesn't have anything to do with your OS

Comment: It's due a bad disk UUID, but anyway, the recover solution is equal to any issue like this, select the old entry that was default just before the problem.

Answer (score 1):

These are the steps to change the efi boot order on a Debian system:

On the BusyBox, load kernel module for the fs, in our case:

```
# modprobe ext4
```

Mount the required partitions needed. Note that root fs is on sda3 in our particular case:

```
# mkdir /mnt
# mount -t ext4 /dev/sda3 /mnt
# mount /proc /mnt/proc
# mount /sys /mnt/sys
```

Chroot into it:

```
# chroot /mnt
```

Load the kernel modules needed to mount the filesystems and to work with efibootmgr:

```
# modprobe efivars
# modprobe vfat
# modprobe efivarfs
```

Mount the required path:

```
# mount -t efivarfs efivarfs /sys/firmware/efi/efivars
```

Now, you can play with efibootmgr:

```
# bin/efibootmgr -v
# bin/efibootmgr -o 0005,0004,0000,0001,0003,0001,0002
```

End with the chroot and exit:

```
# sync
# exit
```

Reboot and enjoy.